# Java: replacing characters in a String

Tags: java, string

I have a `String` that represents a time value and is stored in the following format:

```
1:31:25
```

I would like to replace the colons and change the format to:

```
1h 31m 25s
```

What function in Java will let me replace the first two colons with `'h '` and `'m '`, and the end of the string with `'s'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String time = "1:31:25";
String formattedTime = time.replaceFirst(":","h ").replaceFirst(":","m ").concat("s");
```

Comment: I love your version with concat ;)

Comment: which reminds me: is it still true that `.concat(zero_length_string_variable)` is faster than `+ zero_length_string_variable` or + is also 'smart' in recent VMs?

Answer (score 8):

You could do something like this:

```
String[] s = myString.split(":");
String.format("%sh %sm %ss", s);
```

Or even compact!

```
String.format("%sh %sm %ss", myString.split(":"));
```

Comment: For greater effect, I'd inline `s`.

Answer (score 2):

Repeated use of the [String.replaceFirst()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method would help you here.

Simply replace your first ':' with the 'h', then apply again for 'm' etc.

There are additional options, which may be more appropriate/robust etc. depending on your circumstances.

[Regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) may be useful here, to help you parse/split up such a string.

Or given that you're parsing/outputting times, it may also be worth looking at [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and its ability to parse/output date/time combinations.

In fact, if you're storing that date as a string, you may want to revist that decision. Storing it as a date object (of whatever variant) is more typesafe, will protect you against invalid values, and allow you to perform arithmetic etc on these.

Answer (score 2):

```
String input = "1:31:25";
String[] tokens = input.split(":");
String output = tokens[0] + "h " + tokens[1] + "m " + tokens[2] + "s";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression and substitution:

```
    String input = "1:31:25";
    String expr = "(\\d+):(\\d+):(\\d+)";
    String substitute = "$1h $2m $3s";
    String output = input.replaceAll(expr, substitute);
```

An alternative is to parse and output the String through Date:

```
    DateFormat parseFmt = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    DateFormat displayFmt = new SimpleDateFormat("H'h' mm\'m' ss's'");
    Date d = parseFmt.parse(input);
    output = displayFmt.format(d);
```

Comment: Why do you use `[\\d]` instead of just `\d`?

Comment: Just habit and quick fire response ;) Clearly no need for `[]` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] timeStr = "1:31:25".split(":");
StringBuffer timeStrBuf = new StringBuffer();
timeStrBuf.append(timeStr[0]);
timeStrBuf.append("h ");
timeStrBuf.append(timeStr[1]);
timeStrBuf.append("m ");
timeStrBuf.append(timeStr[2]);
timeStrBuf.append("s");
```

Comment: I would prefer StringBuilder over StringBuffer, just because of the lack of excessive synchronisation. Just nitpicking, though!

Answer (score 0):

Use **split()**

```
String s = "1:31:25";
String[] temp = s.split(":");
System.out.println(s[0]+"h"+" "+s[1]+"m"+" "+s[2]+"s");
```